# How can I select the function and its derivative with the smallest or largest index from a list of function and function derivatives?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of functions and their derivatives.

How can I select the function and its derivative with the smallest or largest index, provided that both the function and its derivative are in the list?

For example, given the list

`vars = {U[1][t], U[2][t], U[3][t], U[5][t], U[6][t], U[7][t], U[3]'[t], U[5]'[t], U[6]'[t]}`,

I want to select the function and its derivative with the smallest index, which would be `{U[3][t], U[3]'[t]}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) to retrieve the indices of functions and derivatives, then [`Intersection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Intersection.html) to get only those that are present in both lists. Afterward, use [`Min`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Min.html) or [`Max`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Max.html) or [`MinMax`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinMax.html) to retrieve the smallest or the largest.

```
MinMax@Intersection[Cases[vars, U[x_][t] :> x], Cases[vars, U[x_]'[t] :> x]]
(* {3, 6} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
vars = {U[1][t], U[2][t], U[3][t], U[5][t], U[6][t], U[7][t], 
  U[3]'[t], U[5]'[t], U[6]'[t]}

min = First@Intersection[D[vars, t], vars]

{Integrate[min, t], min}
```

> {U[3][t], Derivative[1][U[3]][t]}

Answer (score 2):

```
MinMax @ Cases[{a_, __} :> a] @ Split @ Sort @
    Cases[vars, U[a_][_] | _[_][U[a_]][_] :> a]
```

{3, 6}